# unbind click, but keep eventPreventDefault();

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, bind, unbind

I'm trying to us unbind a click on an animation until the animation finishes to keep overlapping animiations from happening. The unbind works fine, but of course, then the event.preventDefault stops working and my button/link becomes active again. I'm not sure how to work my way around this.

Shortened version of the code is:

```
$('a.Next').bind('click', SlideFwd);
function SlideFwd(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a.Next').unbind();
    $('ul.GridviewList').animate({
        left: '-=800px'
        }, 'slow', function() {
        $('a.Next').bind('click', SlideFwd);    
    });
};
```

and the html is:

```
<div>

    <div class="SlideControl">
        <p class="Pages"><span class="ProdCountDisplay">#</span> of <span class="ProdCountTotal">10</span></p>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="Disabled button_Back Previous" href="#">Prev</a></li>
            <li><a class="button_Next Next" href="#">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="GridviewList">
        <li class="ProdWrap">This is a slider space 1</li>
        <li class="ProdWrap"> This is a slider space 2</li>
        <li class="ProdWrap"> This is a slider space 3</li>
        <li class="ProdWrap"> This is a slider space 4</li>
        <li class="ProdWrap"> This is a slider space 5 </li>
        <li class="ProdWrap">This is a slider space 6 </li>
        <li class="ProdWrap"> This is a slider space 7</li>
        <li class="ProdWrap"> This is a slider space 8 </li>
        <li class="ProdWrap"> This is a slider space 9 </li>
        <li class="ProdWrap"> This is a slider space 10 </li>
    </ul> <!-- ul.Gridviewlist -->
</div>
```

A complete working version is here:
http://iwrb.idleprattle.com/Slider.htm
(only the next has the unbind/bind set up now)

I also tried taking the preventDefault outside the function SlideFwd, but it must unbind that too. I.E.

```
$('a.Next').click(function(){e.preventDefault();});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$('a.Next').bind('click', SlideFwd);

...

$('a.Next').unbind().bind('click',function(e){e.preventDefault();});

...

$('a.Next').unbind().bind('click', SlideFwd);
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked with one minor change:
$('a.Next').unbind().bind('click',function(){e.preventDefault();});
changed to 
$('a.Next').unbind().bind('click',function(e){e.preventDefault();});

Comment: Ah yeah, hadn't tested it, missed the e.  Answer updated for posterity!

Answer (score 0):

Why not removing the href-attribute from the link. It makes no use there, a cursor can be set via CSS, and if an a-element has no href, there's nothing to prevent from if no event-handler is attached.