# Trigger e.preventDefault() outside click method

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using the [Jquery Boostrap tab method](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).
Is it possible to prevent the default click method in a method other than the click method?

I am using AnuglarJS so I was hoping this could be easily fixed/hacked without having to redesign the whole tab pane in AngularJS.

I can change tabs by using Jquery

```
$('#tabId a[href="#s' + targetId + '"]').tab('show');
```

So can I prevent the click with something like

```
$('#tabId a[href="#s' + targetId + '"]').preventDefault();
```

Or

```
    $('#tabId a[href="#s' + targetId + '"]').addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked the events the plugin provides, to see if they are preventable?

Comment: You seem to be mixing jQuery's `$` with vanilla-js' `addEventListener`.

Comment: I know :) That was for illustrating purposes ;)

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean, can you provide the Angular JS code and markup?

Comment: It can be easily fixed by wrapping tab functionality into the directive. Or better stick to existing solution, ui-bootstrap or angular-strap. That's a good example of 'don't use jQuery in Angular'. jQuery can be used to supplement directives, not to substitute them.

Answer (score 1):

The `ngClick` directive exposes a `$event` variable.

In your `ng-click` attribute, just add `$event.preventDefault();`.

For example, if you had:

`<a href="#" ng-click="doSomething();">Do something</a>`

You would just change it to:

`<a href="#" ng-click="doSomething(); $event.preventDefault();">Do something</a>`

OR

You can pass the `$event` variable to your method.

`<a href="#" ng-click="doSomething($event);">Do something</a>`

Then call `preventDefault()` in your method.

```
$scope.doSomething = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent the default click method without capturing the click event. Would this not work for you?

```
$('#tabId a[href="#s' + targetId + '"]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: It would not be preferrable since I have a ng-click method on the a element and sending variables from the scope to the angular method

Comment: This doesn't work at all since the click event is not beeing triggered by Jquery.

Comment: I'm afraid I've never used Angular so I'm not familiar with it, maybe Angular introduces something different. But this is only a method of adding an event listener to the element. It doesn't care how the event is triggered. Whether it's with a mouse click or a jquery.trigger('click') or elem.click() is irrelevant. If the click event of the element is triggered this function will run and prevent the default action.

Answer (score 0):

This previous answer to a similar situation seems to address the preventDefault properly, but is similar to Gregg Duncan's answer.  The modest difference is in the way the bind and unbind calls are using the local context of the selected object.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5827040/2266428